# How to do high frequency simulations in simulation softwares (proteus, multisim, etc)

Tags: simulation, buck, high-frequency, proteus, multisim

So i am trying to build a buck converter which requires switching at high frequencies. Before making the whole circuit however, i decided to use a circuit simulation software so that i can experiment with the values of the components and trying to see if a concept works or not. However, the problem comes when simulating the circuit. the simulation time will come down to a snail's pace that it would take a long time to get proper results. I've tried using multiple simulators such as proteus and multisim. Both of them perform poorly when working on high frequencies. Is there any way to lighten the workload for simulating these sorts of circuits?

Comment: Use a proper simulation tool like microcap (free and fully loaded last time I checked).

Comment: Falstad can do almost realtime for complex circuits. Microcap cannot

Comment: Try this https://tinyurl.com/yylahz2v  , press reset, change any parameter on the fly repeat

Comment: What are you trying to simulate?  The fast time/switching time behavior of the power train, or the overall closed loop performance of the supply?

Comment: This is realy a hidden "what simulator do you recommend?" question, which might not comply with the rules.